# Find HKObject by UUID

Tags: ios, healthkit, hkhealthstore, hksamplequery

In my app users can do workouts and they get listed in my app. If a user wants to delete a workout inside my app, I'd like to offer him to also delete it from HealthKit. But I can't seem to find a way to fetch an `HKObject` by it's uuid?!? Is that not possible? Cause creating a `HKSampleQuery` and use `uuid == <The-workout-UUID>` does not work. It will crash any say that this keypath (even though ever HKObject has an uuid) is not valid...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `HKQuery` convenience method `predicateForObjectWithUUID:` to match an object with a specific UUID ([documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkquery/1614783-predicateforobjectwithuuid?langua_7)).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Somehow missed that one!